# How can I detect whether the install process is running?

Tags: 7, installation

I'm looking for a way to reliably detect whether Drupal's install process is currently running, either via `drush site-install` or `install.php`.

The immediate problem I'm trying to solve is that I have some settings (using Redis as cache backend) in `settings.php` which cause the installation to fail. So I'd like to wrap that block of settings in something like `if (!drupal_installation_is_currently_running()) { … }`

I have not managed to figure out how that can reliably be determined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for [`drupal_installation_attempted()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_installation_attempted/7):

> Returns TRUE if a Drupal installation is currently being attempted.

Comment: This doesn't work on settings.php

Comment: It wouldn't do - Drupal isn't bootstrapped when settings.php is included

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution:

```
if (defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE') && constant('MAINTENANCE_MODE') === 'install')
```

If null, or another value, then not in install mode. Unfortunately, there is some code that executes before the install.php redirect is triggered. So you might still run into problems before the `define('MAINTENANCE_MODE', 'install');` is called inside of install.php.

This solutions is working well for me in that it allows me to set `$conf['preprocess_js'] = true` when `$_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']` equals 'test' or 'live'.

Comment: Thanks @jonMcL that worked for me on Drupal 9.4.x